# database multi table complex join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, where-clause

I have 3 tables and request,requestcondition,customer

request contain customer_id which refers to customer table id and contain employee_id

requestcondition contain request_id which refers to request table id

i want to select request details and requestcondition details and cutomer according to the employee_id

Comment: That's not remotely complex. Those are basic JOINS. Have you tried it? are you getting wrong results? less results than you expect?

Comment: You have to put some effort, mate. Include the code that you have tried and the error that you are getting. Sometimes it is satisfactionary enough to see that the OP is keen and uses the site as a tool for gaining knowledge rathar than copying code.

Comment: The idea of complexity is relative to the individuals current skill. Thus it is complex for him if he thinks it is.

Comment: i am very beginner in sql so its complex to me and i didnot try any sql cause i dont know sql enough so i am asking how to make this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM request r 
INNER JOIN customer c ON r.customer_id = c.customer_id
INNER JOIN requestcondition rc ON r.request_id = rc.request_id 
WHERE r.employee_id = 123
```

Comment: its not working cause the employee_id is in request table not customer table

Comment: @Body if its in request table then change the column name from `c.employee_id` to `r.employee_id`

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem?